# Публикация приложения в App Store под другим именем

Tags: ipad, ios, xcode, appstore, iphone

Имеется аккаунт разработчика Apple.
Могу ли я опубликовать в App Store приложение не под своим именем, а под вымышленным именем?

Разрабатываю приложение для компании, а заново регистрировать в App Store как компанию не хочется.

Comment: Задайте себе вопрос: "Зачем придумали программу сертификации разработчиков?"

Comment: Публикуйте под своим именем, это нормальная практика. А компанию зарегистрировать в принципе и можно, но это лишние телодвижения, хотя и не сложные, на хабре была статья, поищите если интересно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Компания должна предоставить, Вас как агента для своего аккаунта разработчика Apple. Вам ни чего не нужно покупать и регистрировать, это должна делать компания. Для регистрации компании потребуется отправка факсом всех документов подтверждающие валидность компании!

Comment: в том то и дело, что у компании нету своего аккаунта в апп сторе. 
приложение хотят выпустить сейчас, но регистрация компании в апп сторе займет 1-2 месяца

Comment: Тогда выпускайте под своим именем. Сейчас, если я не ошибаюсь можно предавать приложения с одного акка на другой. Если это так, то Вы можете запустить под своим именем приложение, а когда компнаия получит лицензиюю передать ей. Но надо это поизучать. Точно не знаю.